# On a protractor helper function, how can I know if browser.get was ever called?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, protractor, helper

I'm creating a helper function for my protractor tests to log in the application only if necessary.

That is useful to allow me to run each test in isolation to debug it and, when running the whole suite, I get a little performance boost from not having to log in before every test.

I have to actually login in two situations:

1. If no page was ever loaded (`browser.get()` was not called).
2. We are on a page, but not logged in yet.

Situation 2 is easy. The application has an element that is shown on all pages when the user is logged in.

The hard part is 1. If I try to find the element that indicates the user is logged in before I load any pages, I get the following error:

```
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"
```

And I didn't see anything on the protractor API or source code that could help me determine if any pages were already loaded.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question, even though I don't think it is a good idea to have tests in non-deterministic state after you do something.

Only way to know if get was called I can think of is checking that `browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()` returns desired URL, or doesn't return about:blank.
But you'd have to wait some time, because getCurrentUrl returns about:blank even after get is called, but page is not fully loaded. So I'd do something like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var URL;
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; 
    //get rid of automatic check that would give you the "Protractor Sync Error"
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('.ng-scope')),500)
                .then(function(){},function(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                        URL = url;
                        if(URL == "about:blank"){
                            console.log('no get before');
                            // your login function here - no get was called before this wait
                        }
                    });
                });
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

});
```

Question is if you even need to check for about:blank, because in your case it might be enough to check for that .ng-scope, or your "login element". But this should give you a kickstart.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it did get me on the right direction. What did the trick for me was putting the login, using `browser.wait()` on a before function (I used `beforeAll`). Of course `browser.ignoreSynchronization` is very important too, but that I had already seen.

Comment: And you are right, I did simplify the solution somewhat by just directly waiting for my login element (`element(by.id('IdOfLoginElement')).getText`) and calling the login function on the error handler. I didn't really need the URL.

Comment: And, a conceptual comment, it is a conscious choice starting the test on an already logged in page. The app has internal navigation, so each test usually starts by changing the location, which gives some guarantees on the state. And I can always force the page load (and log in again) if the tests become flaky.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I just think it is a god idea to have tests that can run on their own, I actually have something similar in test suite. Because we have angular hidden after 4 other clicks in non-angular pages, and it takes like 10s to get there from blank page :)